# Program won't run properly

Tags: java, if-statement, crash

So I wrote this program but for some reason my else statement won't work.
If i input "e" for example my program will simply crash... when its actually supposed to return "Invalid Input"
Can someone please help me?

=========================================================================

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AbsValue2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number:");
  String num = input.nextLine();
  Double num2 = new Double(Double.parseDouble(num));
  Double abs_val = new Double(Math.sqrt(num2 * num2));

  if (num.matches("[+-]?[\\d]+[.]*"))
    System.out.println("The absolute value of " + num + " is |" + abs_val + "|");
  else if (num.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*.[\\d]+"))
    System.out.println("The absolute value of " + num + " is |" + abs_val + "|");
  else
    System.out.println("Invalid input");

  }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to parse it before you check if it is valid.

Comment: Easy fix would be to wrap in try and catch, and in your catch output invalid input!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is here:

```
Double num2 = new Double(Double.parseDouble(num));
```

if num is "e", then you will get a `NumberFormatException`.

You can use `Scanner.hasNextDouble{}`, to check, or try/catch that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing a `NumberFormatException` *before* the if statement is reached, because of this line:

```
Double num2 = new Double(Double.parseDouble(num));
```

You need to check the validity *before* parsing it.